# Изменить src у iframe javascript'ом

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я решаю вопрос:

Есть пару полей на странице и Яндекс.кнопка.
Кнопка - это `iframe` (это так у Яндексов).
В `src` этого `iframe` куча параметров. 
Но один из этих параметров нужно задавать *"на лету"*, в процессе заполнения пользователем полей на странице.
Я прописал в нем изначально что-то заметное, а потом - меняю на то, что нужно.
Получилась вот такая громоздкая конструкция:

```
$('#frame').attr(
   'src', 
   document.getElementById('frame').src.replace('JS-REPLACE-ID', data)
);
```

Мне не нравится, что часть команды написана на `jQuery`, а часть - на простом `JS`. Но по-другому она не работает.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы показали рабочий вариант, но не показали нерабочий, так что сказать "что не так" трудно. Пробуйте:

На jQuery:

```js
var myFrame = $('#myframe');
myFrame.attr('src', myFrame.attr('src').replace(/blank/, 'bank'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="myframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

На Vanilla.js

```js
var myFrame = document.getElementById('myframe');
myFrame.setAttribute('src', myFrame.getAttribute('src').replace(/blank/, 'bank'));
```

```html
<iframe id="myframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```