# заменить src="" во фрейме

Tags: html, iframe

При вставке в форму кода от видео ссылки, необходимо что бы данное видео проигрывалось в плеере ниже.
например youtube.com/watch?v=tHZXqpEpAik            код=tHZXqpEpAik
То есть вставив код и нажав Go.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

src="" во фрейме передалось нужное значение.

```html
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<style>
  body {
    background: #EDEDED url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/xW7UB2DqQqUjoaurjIZ9hEKsn8cyXXZ0_ZTSKbReSxYvRv-9zFJUejzU_DQY0vsSGMyWw=s85);
    color: #000000
  }
</style>
<center>
  <div>
    <form action="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" onsubmit="this.action+=this.elements.results.value" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="results" value="">
      <input type="reset">
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A7ZaI-hhVJI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe></div>
</center>
```

Comment: возможно, дубликат: [Изменить src у iframe javascript'ом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647265/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-src-%d1%83-iframe-javascript%d0%be%d0%bc?rq=1)

Здесь нужно лишь создать кнопку, при нажатии на которую будет выполняться код из ссылки на вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Используем для этого самый обычный JavaScript.

Сначала удалим из формы action, т.к. нам не надо выполнять get/post запрос. submit заменим на button и добавим к нему onClick, в который напишем название функции, которую сразу же и напишем.

Наша цель:

1. Получить значение текстового поля. Для этого мы даём ему id, и при помощи document.getElementById получаем текстовое поле и его значение (value).
2. Сгенерировать iframe с новой ссылкой. **Тут есть нюанс - нельзя просто так вставить ссылку с ютуба в iframe, нужно заменить в ссылке watch на embed, только так будет работать** *(смотрим код чтобы понять)*. Преобразуем ссылку, создаем переменную с кодом iframe и новой ссылкой.
3. Вставить новый iframe вместо старого. Для этого мы оборачиваем iframe (тот что изначально показывается) в div, задаём ему id, находим его так же как и текстовое поле, и меняем innerHTML (содержимое) на переменную с новым iframe. Вуаля!

*P.S.: JS код можно поместить между тегами* `<script></script>` *перед закрывающим тегом* `</body>`

```js
//находим div c iframe
var iframeContainer = document.getElementById("videoblock");
 
//функция выполняется при клике на кнопку
function ChangeVideo() {
    //получаем значение поля
    var videoUrl = document.getElementById("url").value;
    //преобразуем ссылку, иначе видео не вставится  
    videoUrl = videoUrl.replace("watch?v=", "embed/");
 
    //генерируем новый iframe
    var iframeCode = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + videoUrl + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    //вставляем новый iframe в контейнер
    iframeContainer.innerHTML = iframeCode;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="url" value="">
      <input type="reset">   
      <input type="button" value="Go" onClick="ChangeVideo()">
    </form>    
    
    <div id="videoblock">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A7ZaI-hhVJI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**P.P.S.: !В сниппетах этого сайта код iframe не выполняется! Чтобы убедиться в работоспособности, нужно скопировать код и запустить у себя на компьютере**

Comment: **Rikky** С прошедшими вас праздниками. Благодарю за пояснения и за решенную проблему.
Я далек от написания сайтов и языков программирования (пытаюсь писать для себя простенькие странички). Еще раз с прошедшими, код проверил всё нормально работает.

Comment: @Алекс Если ответ вам помог - примите его проставив галку.